# Eclipse run configuration that excludes jars from classpath

Tags: eclipse, gwt, jar, jersey, ektorp

How can I create an Eclipe Run Configuration that exclude some jars from the classpath?!

BACKGROUND EXPLANATION:

I'm working on webapp that uses Embedded Jetty as Web Server, Ektorp library to fetch data from a CouchDB database, Jersey to provide REST service and GWT for the frontend.

All these four libraries are imported in the same Eclipse project:
- Ektorp, Embedded Jetty and Jersey imported through Maven
- GWT imported with jars

Unfortunately Ektorp and GWT somehow enters in conflict using a different version of the class: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme

I've tried moving the GWT packages to another project and importing the Jetty/Ektorp/Jersey project but then GWT wasn't able to find the Jersey resources...

So reformulating the question for this specific project:

How can I create an Eclipe Run Configuration that runs the Embedded Jetty server and excludes the GWT jars from the classpath?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What should work:

1. Go to the run configuration menu
2. Select your run configuration
3. Click on the classpath tab
4. Remove the default classpath under *User Entries*
5. Select *User Entries* and add your project with *Add Projects...*
6. Select the added project and add your libs with *Add JARs...* leaving out the unwanted ones.